# Kan extension of a composition

Tags: category-theory, kan-extensions

I'm trying to prove this result, but I'm stuck. Let $f:C\to D$, $g:D\to E$ and $i: C\to B$ be functors and suppose (1) that all the kan extensions i'm about to name exist globally and (2) not sure it is needed but let's say that $i$ is fully faithful. Then $lan_i(gf)\simeq g\circ lan_i(f)$. My strategy so far consists in noticing that we know that $[B,D](lan_i(f), -)\simeq [C, D](f, -\circ i)$ and we want to show that $[B,E](g\circ lan_i(f), -)\simeq [C, E](g\circ f, -\circ i)$ so in some sense this proof would be a one liner of the form: apply the same functor to isomorphic things and you'll get isomorphic things, but I am failing to make this intuition precise

Comment: Are you sure you've copied the exercise correctly? I suspect this is false. We may even need $i$ to be essentially surjective as well, i.e. an equivalence, and then the result is fairly trivial since left Kan extension should amount to just precomposing with the inverse equivalence

Comment: This is not an exercise, just something I believe to be true. It could also be false, as far as i know

Comment: If $B=1$ is the terminal category, $lan_i(gf)\simeq g\circ lan_i(f)$ is just saing that $g$ preserves the colimit of $f$, which, taking for example $C$ the empty category, $D$ that has an initial object, and a g that doesn't preserve it, is false.

Answer (score 2):

A Kan-extension which has your property is called an [*absolute Kan extension*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+extension#Pointwise). Absolute Kan-extension are in particular pointwise Kan-extension, but not all Kan-extensions are pointwise. This means that the property that you are trying to prove will not hold for all Kan-extensions.